# Не подключается внешний файл CSS

Tags: html, css, html5, css3, веб-программирование

Не подключается внешний файл CSS,но если внести теже стили из CSS файла в html все работает, путь к файлу проверял несколько раз, все правильно. Почему стили могут не работать?

```
<link href="/resources/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

```
/* Eric Meyer's CSS Reset */
html, body, div, span, applet, object, iframe,
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, pre,
a, abbr, acronym, address, big, cite, code,
del, dfn, em, img, ins, kbd, q, s, samp,
small, strike, strong, sub, sup, tt, var,
b, u, i, center,
dl, dt, dd, ol, ul, li,
fieldset, form, label, legend,
table, caption, tbody, tfoot, thead, tr, th, td,
article, aside, canvas, details, embed,
figure, figcaption, footer, header, hgroup,
menu, nav, output, ruby, section, summary,
time, mark, audio, video {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
    font-size: 100%;
    font: inherit;
    vertical-align: baseline;
}
/* HTML5 display-role reset for older browsers */
article, aside, details, figcaption, figure,
footer, header, hgroup, menu, nav, section {
    display: block;
}
body {
    line-height: 1;
    background-image:resursi/background.jpg;
}
ol, ul {
    list-style: none;
}
blockquote, q {
    quotes: none;
}
blockquote:before, blockquote:after,
q:before, q:after {
    content: '';
    content: none;
}
table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    border-spacing: 0;
}
/* End of Eric Meyer's CSS Reset */

article, aside, details, figcaption, figure, footer, header, hgroup, main, nav, section, summary {
    display: block;
}
body {
    font: 12px/18px Arial, sans-serif;
    width: 100%;
}
.wrapper {
    width: 1000px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}


/* Header
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
.header {
    height: 150px;
    background: #00FFFF;
}


/* Middle
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
.content {
    background-color:#FFFFFF;
}




/* Footer
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
.footer {
    height: 100px;
    background: #BFF08E;
}
```

или что то не так с оператором? где я ошибся?

https://i.stack.imgur.com/fH5ny.jpg теперь выскакивает эта ошибка

Comment: /resources/style.css дробь в конце убрать, первая дробь это корень сайта, у вас site.ru/resources/style.css так лежит?

Comment: файл лежит
    /public_html/resources/style.css

Comment: public_html это папка внутри домена или просто на хостинге вы смотрите?

Comment: В хроме или огнелисе в инструментах разработчика (Ф12 нажать) на закладках консоль и сеть есть какие нибудь ругательства/ошибки?

Comment: нет ошибок нет, но я заметил что во в кладке Elements в Styles вообще нет того, что я писал

Comment: После открытия инструментов, нужно страницу перегрузить по контрол+ф5, что бы увидеть все ошибки и если после этого ошибок не будет, значит все ресурсы на странице подгружены правильно.

Comment: Resource interpreted as Stylesheet but transferred with MIME type    text/html:  за ошибку считается?

Comment: Со стилем вроде нормально все. Имя файла 1в1 как в хтмл (даже бальшие/малые буквы)? Сделайте так <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/resources/style.css"> т.б. укажите тип явно.

Comment: не, все также ничего, а в хроме в Sources должен быть виден в моем файле со стилями сам код? просто там пусто

Comment: И в сорс должен быть виден и в нетворк он должен подгружаться отдельным реквестом - там тоже нет?

Comment: не сам файл есть и там и там, но если в него заглянуть там пусто

Comment: Пуст? Т.б. если его по урлу открыть - файл пустой, ну тогда, думаю, вы нашли в чем проблема?

Comment: теперь появились ошибки в Chrome

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Во первых почему в конце стоит слеш?
Должно быть:

```
<link href="/resources/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

Далее проверяем правильно ли указан путь, в начале стоит слеш, значит путь будет с корня сайта, например:

```
ya.ru/resources/style.css
```

И если вы зайдёте по этому пути в браузере вы должны получить этот файл, так происходит?

И как получается что `<link>` у вас находится вместе с CSS, он должен быть в HTML документе, а если это так и есть, то остальной CSS должен быть в заключён в тег `<style>`

Так же стоит убедится в том что файл действительно залит на сервер удачно.

Далее обратите внимание на файл htaccess, возможно в нём что-то не так настроено.

Comment: <link>    находится не в одном файле со стилями, просто просили показать файлик стилей
 если зайти по url css файла там пусто, но путь я уже несколько раз проверил.....это может быть что-то еще?

Comment: `если зайти по url css файла там пусто` - так так не должно быть, значит сервер не правильно файл отдаёт, где это всё у вас находится, на хостинге?

Comment: да на хостинге (Hostinger)

Comment: Может вы предоставите ссылку и я гляну, что не так?

Comment: на свой сайт??(если да то вот poligonfotester.xyz/)(правда там ничего нет)

Comment: Вы файл .htaccess не создавали? И вы уверены что файл что-то содержит? Попробуйте через FTP посмотреть его ещё раз и убедится что он не пустой и вообще существует на сервере, что очень на это похоже.

Comment: файл htaccess создавал вот его содержимое http://imgur.com/6bvBKlJ и уже несколько раз проверил css файл не пустой....

Comment: Удалите файл htaccess и попробуйте, если всё заработает, значит дело в нём и вы что-то не так настроили, что скорее всего и есть.

Comment: Спасибо, все заработало, значит я что не так написал....

Answer (score -1):

`<style>@import "resources/style.css"</style>` МБ ТАК

Comment: Извините, можно несколько поподробней? Или это только ваши предположения?